# How to import and run Nifi source code in eclipse

Tags: apache-nifi, minify

[image]How to import and run Apache NiFi using eclipse IDE. There is no documentation for development purpose, as I wanted to change the source code for UI related. Is there any guide for import and run Apache NiFi(maven project).

Below is the project structure where nifi is the parent directory and all are its module. So, how can I run run using eclipse, run configuration required.

I just wanted to modify the whole NiFi UI.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very extensive [Developer Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html) with discussion around common development patterns and problems, a [Contributor Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Contributor+Guide) with instructions for cloning the git repository and importing the code into various development environments, and I have done [presentations on developing custom processors](https://github.com/alopresto/slides/tree/master/dws_barcelona_2019). Do these not address your questions? We are always welcome to feedback on how to improve documentation and ease of use.

Comment: I have updated my question I actually I just wanted to customize the code, So I just wanted to know how I can run in eclipse.

Comment: @Andy Your presentation link is broken

Comment: The link still works for me. It goes to a github repository hosting my presentations -- this specific page contains the summary of 3 talks given in Barcelona and the PDFs of the slides listed above.

Comment: If that link still doesn't work for you, try https://github.com/alopresto/slides then click `dws_barcelona_2019` in the directory listing.